# Bold font does not work in xepersian

Tags: fonts, bold, xepersian, persian, pifont

My documents language is Persian and I am using xepersian package for the matter. The font I defined for my document which is an MS thesis is `B nazanin`, we are told to use the font and can't change it. Apparently it does not support the bold font. Since I cannot use other fonts, what can be done about it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
%\setlist[itemize,1]{label={\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\textbullet}}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{B Nazanin}
\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=2]{IranNastaliq}
\defpersianfont\titr[Scale=1]{B Titr}
\defpersianfont\traffic[Scale=1]{B Traffic}
\deflatinfont\calibri{Calibri}

\begin{document}
\chapter{مقدمه}
\section{پیشگفتار}


در دنیای امروزی با حجم وسیعی از اطلاعات روبرو هستیم که بوسیله‌ی سنسورهای طبیعی و مصنوعی گرفته و ثبت شده‌اند. این اطلاعات عموماً یا تکراری هستند و شامل چندین نسخه از جهان فیزیکی مشابه هستند و یا شامل چیزی فراتر از اطلاعات مورد نظر ما و آنچه ما به دنبال آن هستیم می‌شوند. اطلاعات مرتبط و مورد نظر ما معمولاً در ابعاد بسیار پایین‌تر قرار دارند. استخراج این اطلاعات به یکی از دغدغه‌های امروز دنیای فناوری اطلاعات بدل شده است، اینکه بتوان تشخیص داد که داده‌ی مطلوب و مورد نظر ما در کجای داده‌ی مشاهده شده قرار دارد. 
نمایش تنک داده‌ها ابزاری قدرتمند است که در زمینه‌های نمایش و فشرده‌سازی داده‌ها در ابعاد بالا مورد استفاده قرار می‌گیرد.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a compete code which begin with `\documentclass..`  and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: @salimbou Done!

Comment: Have you installed `B Nazanin Bold` in your OS? If you only have regular, then of course, boldface is not supported.